# Why am I getting this error when trying to use postgis

Tags: python, django, geospatial, gdal, geos

When I'm making migrations, I get this error.

```
(project) PS D:\University\FYP\final_project\land_management_system> python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\University\FYP\final_project\land_management_system\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\University\FYP\final_project\land_management_system\manage.py", line 18, in main    
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\University\FYP\final_project\project\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\University\FYP\final_project\project\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 416, in execute    
    django.setup()
  File "D:\University\FYP\final_project\project\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\University\FYP\final_project\project\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 124, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "D:\University\FYP\final_project\project\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 27, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "D:\University\FYP\final_project\project\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 52, in autodiscover  
    autodiscover_modules("admin", register_to=site)
  File "D:\University\FYP\final_project\project\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 58, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module("%s.%s" % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\University\FYP\final_project\land_management_system\core\admin.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.admin import OSMGeoAdmin
ImportError: cannot import name 'OSMGeoAdmin' from 'django.contrib.gis.admin' (D:\University\FYP\final_project\project\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\__init__.py)
```

Here's imports from my admin code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User, Land, LandTransfers, NFTs, AuthTokens, TaxesFees
from django.contrib.gis.admin import OSMGeoAdmin
```

I've tried adding custom path for GEOS and GDAL in settings, still it didn't help:

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r"C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal308.dll"
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = r"C:\OSGeo4W\bin\geos_c.dll"
```